# Why isn't a setting in php.ini not being loaded?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I'm trying to get PHP to display a warning when we call an undefined variable.

`php.ini` has the line `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`.

The trouble is, strict warning messages are not being output to the browser.

In the PHP script, echoing `E_ALL | E_STRICT` shows the value `32767`.

Yet the value returned by `error_reporting()` is `22519`. I've read online that this value actually matches `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED`.

Is the value in my `php.ini` for `error_reporting` potentially being overridden? If so, how would I investigate where its value is being set? `error_reporting` is not being set anywhere in the script. I'm editing the correct `php.ini` file, as I'm editing `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` which is specified by `phpinfo()`.

### Edit

`phpinfo()` includes the following information:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/curl.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/gd.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini 

error_reporting no value (Local)    no value (Master)
```

Comment: Could it be that its being overridden within your application itself like in a config file thats being run before any other code? Does it say 22519 for `error_reporting` in your `phpinfo ()`?

Comment: Well, it can possibly be set in `.htaccess` as well.

Comment: Why isn't this question not understandable?

Comment: Do a `phpinfo()` and (i) post the master and local values for "error_reporting" (ii) check the value for "Loaded Configuration File" and make sure that PHP is loading the right .ini file.

Comment: are you sure that the php.ini file you're editing is the one being loaded? Regardless of what phpinfo is saying, perhaps the script in question is relying on another ini file

Comment: Interestingly, `phpinfo()` is displaying *no value* for `error_reporting`. I am editing the correct `php.ini`, I believe, as editing the value for `display_errors` is having the desired effect.

Comment: What OS you using? Have you definitely restarted apache? You could introduce an error in the file and restart apache to make sure its actually loading that file and something crazy isn't going on.

Comment: Using Linux (Mint). Contrary to what I said about `display_errors` previously, setting it to `Off` still shows the value `On` according to `phpinfo()`. It could indeed be that another ini is being loaded. I'm sure I'm restarting, since I'm doing `sudo service apache2 stop` which results in the page not loading, followed by `sudo service apache2 start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that **I had introduced a syntax error into php.ini**.

I presume that the values I mentioned in my question from `phpinfo()` were PHP's default values that it sets. They were not getting touched, since PHP was not able to load its ini file.

Thanks to all who responded here helping to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reload apache after changing the php.ini file, in order to see the changes take effect. Depending on your distribution something like `sudo service apache2 reload` or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` should do the job.

Comment: Yes, I am already starting Apache after each edit. Changing the value of `display_errors` in the same `php.ini` does have an effect, which indicates to me that there's something else wrong.

Comment: Presumably it must be getting changed after it's importing the php.ini settings. If you put `phpinfo()` in a file, are the `Master value` and `Local value` the same? There's three places I can think of that would be changing it, vhost/httpd.conf, .htaccess, php runtime.

Comment: I'm not so sure now: setting `display_errors` actually does **not** change either in `phpinfo()`, contrary to what I earlier thought. `error_reporting` value in `phpinfo()` is actually showing *no value* for both local and master.

Comment: The vhost configuration file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` doesn't set `error_reporting`. As for `httpd.conf`, `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is actually **empty**.

Comment: Mint probably works similar to Ubuntu then, which has it's Apache configuration in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` rather than the `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Right you are about the location of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.